# Auto execution of a python script inside vscode called from .bat file

Tags: python-3.x, windows, batch-file, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I would like to call visual studio code IDE gui interface opens and launches inside a .bat file and then the vscode ide opens and debug a certain python file automatically after. In addition I would like to have same environment variables that are set from the .bat file , I am wondering if that is doable or not?
Do I need a special vscode plugin for doing that?

As an example in the batch file something tike this.

**Call vscode dbg.py --debug** 
Is there anything similar available.?